# Media Elements Events using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mediaelement

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#videolayer').mediaelementplayer({ defaultVideoWidth: 890, defaultVideoHeight: 400, enableAutosize: true, success: function(media) {
        media.addEventListener('play', function(media) {
            jQuery.post("http://localhost/meshchemia/wp-content/themes/meshchemia/session.php", { "session":"lastcheck" });             
        }, true) };
    }); 
});
```

I'm trying to make an ajax call when the user plays the video, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?  Are there errors on the console, does the code get called at all, does it ever return, etc.

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't do the ajax call.

Comment: Are you confident that `media` is firing the `play` event to execute that function? If inside you put `console.log("play event executed");`, does that log out/ I suspect it wont, in which case are you sure `play` is the correct event to be listening to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#videolayer').mediaelementplayer({ defaultVideoWidth: 890, defaultVideoHeight: 400, enableAutosize: true, success: function(media) {
        media.addEventListener('play', function(media) {
            $.post("http://localhost/meshchemia/wp-content/themes/meshchemia/session.php", { "session":"lastcheck" });             
        }, true) };
    }); 
});
```

If nothing is happening, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to work out whereabouts in your code errors are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  var media = new MediaElement(element, options);

  $(media).on('play', function() {
    console.log('"play" was fired!');
  });

});
```